# Trying to use $set with stringify but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use this function, to edit one space in my mongodb data base, but I am new at it, and I do not understand what is happening. I am getting the error missing ) after argument list. Thank you all for see this.

```
app.put('/factura/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.header({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    var factura = req.body;
    var facturaModel = new FacturaModel({
        nro: factura.nro,
        nit: factura.nit,
        cliente: factura.cliente,
        tarjeta: factura.tarjeta,
        detalles:[{producto: factura.nombre, cantidad: factura.cantidadSeleccionada, precio_unitario: factura.precio}]
    })

    FacturaModel.findByIdAndUpdate({id: req.params.id}, (err, factura) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(factura));
        res.end(JSON.stringify($set: factura));
    });


});
```

Comment: which line the error says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify accepts an *object* as a parameter. You haven't created an object there, so trying to declare `$set` as a property doesn't work. If you want an output such as `{"$set":"foo"}`, then give JSON.stringify an object to stringify:

```
res.end(JSON.stringify({ $set: factura }));
```